# How to send email notification of a bat file result

Tags: java, cmd

I have java code  to find document count for every day. and i have created one bat file for that and when i double click on it will give the result , but if i want that result to send email notification everyday automatic which process is best for that , can any one help me out this. Is it can be done by task scheduler ?

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO! Can you post the Java code you've done?

Comment: I asume you are using Windows, since you have .bat files. You can schedule the Task Scheduler Feature of Windows, to schedule the bat file and to send a notification mail with the output.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to send an email , I suggest you to use the following code inside your scheduler code (I suppose you are using java):

@Scheduled(fixedRate = 60000)

public void myCustomScheduler() {

```
    /**
    Your first processes here ......
    **/ 
    System.out.println("SimpleEmail Start");
    
    String smtpHostServer = "smtp.example.com";
    String emailID = "email_me@example.com";
    
    Properties props = System.getProperties();

    props.put("mail.smtp.host", smtpHostServer);

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
    
    EmailUtil.sendEmail(session, emailID,"SimpleEmail Testing Subject", "SimpleEmail Testing Body");
```

}
https://www.journaldev.com/2532/javamail-example-send-mail-in-java-smtp